# Threading A Method Contained In An Object - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm

I'm writing a program that will analyze changes in the stock market.

Every time the candles on the stock charts are updated, my algorithm scans every chart for certain pieces of data. I've noticed that this process is taking about 0.6 seconds each time, freezing my application. Its not getting stuck in a loop, and there are no other problems like exception errors slowing it down. It just takes a bit of time.

To solve this, I'm trying to see if I can thread the algorithm.

In order to call the algorithm to check over the charts, I have to call this:

checkCharts.RunAlgo();

As threads need an object, I'm trying to figure out how to run the RunAlgo(), but I'm not having any luck.

How can I have a thread run this method in my checkCharts object? Due to back propagating data, I can't start a new checkCharts object. I have to continue using that method from the existing object.

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
M4.ALProj.BotMain checkCharts = new ALProj.BotMain(); 
Thread algoThread = new Thread(checkCharts.RunAlgo);
```

It tells me that the **checkCharts** part of **checkCharts.RunAlgo** is gives me, "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "M4.ALProj.BotMain"*."

In a specific if statement, I was going to put the **algoThread.Start();** Any idea what I did wrong there?

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve this, but ultimately you need a way to manage giving up the control from current (presumably UI) thread to a worker thread. A common way to do this is using async/await, but it depends on how your application is structured. Check out google for async/await and/or other methods of executing on different threads to the UI thread

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] so that we can copy, paste and run your code - then it makes it easy to answer. Yes, this means you will need to spend a few minutes refactoring your code in to a simple stand-alone sample - but then you'll get an excellent answer.

Comment: Your problem (compiler error) is not with the thread but earlier. What the problem is, is hard to tell without knowing what M4, ALProj and BotMain are.

Comment: Your updated code will compile fine. The error message doesn't match what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is actually very simple:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(checkCharts.RunAlgo);
myThread.Start();
```

However, the more complex part is to make sure that when the method `RunAlgo` accesses variables inside the checkCharts object, this happens in a thread-safe manner.

See [Thread Synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679037.aspx) for help on how to synchronize access to data from multiple threads.

Comment: I tried this:
**M4.ALProj.BotMain checkCharts = new ALProj.BotMain();
Thread algoThread = new Thread(checkCharts.RunAlgo);**

It tells me that the checkCharts part of checkCharts.RunAlgo is gives me, "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "M4.ALProj.BotMain"."

In a specific if statement, I was going to put the algoThread.Start();

Any idea what I did wrong there?

Comment: Updated. Sorry, I'm still getting used to how things work around here.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `Task.Run` than `Thread`. `Task.Run` utilizes the `ThreadPool` which has been optimized to handle various loads effectively. You will also get all the goodies of `Task`.

```
await Task.Run(()=> checkCharts.RunAlgo);
```

Comment: await will only work if the calling method is marked as async, and thus all the way up the stack needs to be async. Depending on program architecture, that might not be feasible.

Comment: The calling method doesn't have to be `async`. An `async` method just returns a `Task`. You can use `ContinueWith` if you don't want to have `async` all the way up.

Comment: Using ContinueWith is a method of Tasks, not async/await. Async/await are syntactic sugar around tasks, yes, but you can't just `await` a task from a method not marked as `async`. `The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.`

Comment: `private async Task DoAlgo() { await Task.Run(()=> checkCharts.RunAlgo); }` Then I can call `DoAlgo` from any non `async` method. `private void Method1() { DoAlgo().ContinueWith((task)=> // do whatever) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block. Its a basic boilerplate but you can build on and extend it quite easily.

```
//If M4.ALProj.BotMain needs to be recreated for each run then comment this line and uncomment the one in DoRunParallel()
private static M4.ALProj.BotMain checkCharts = new M4.ALProj.BotMain();
private static object SyncRoot = new object();
private static System.Threading.Thread algoThread = null;
private static bool ReRunOnComplete = false;
public static void RunParallel()
{
    lock (SyncRoot)
    {
        if (algoThread == null)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadStart TS = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoRunParallel);
            algoThread = new System.Threading.Thread(TS);
        }
        else
        {
            //Recieved a recalc call while still calculating
            ReRunOnComplete = true;
        }
    }
}
public static void DoRunParallel()
{
    bool ReRun = false;
    try
    {
        //If M4.ALProj.BotMain needs to be recreated for each run then uncomment this line and comment private static version above
        //M4.ALProj.BotMain checkCharts = new M4.ALProj.BotMain();
        checkCharts.RunAlgo();
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            algoThread = null;
            ReRun = ReRunOnComplete;
            ReRunOnComplete = false;
        }
    }
    if (ReRun)
    {
        RunParallel();
    }
}
```